# How to disable some column or property validation in mvc ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

i want create two view, one view all property validation but second view i want some property validation.
**how to disable validation for other view ?**

```
public partial class Car_Property
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Car_Property()
        {
            this.Cars = new HashSet<Car>();
        }

        public long ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Nullable<long> Model { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Nullable<int> Years { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Remark { get; set; }

        public virtual Model Model1 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }
```

> first view i want all validation but second view only Years validation
>   other ignore.

Comment: You could apply validations using jquery as per the view instead of model.

Comment: @Hp_issei you mean client  site validation ?

Comment: Yes.client side validations.

Comment: I want service site validation sorry

Comment: Then you can create two models with same properties but different validation attributes and use as per the view

Comment: Same name ? Can you explain more ?

Comment: Create two car property models with required attribut as per your view.
In one add required for all and in other model add required only for year property.

Comment: Same name car_property ?  If same name how to use for different view ?

Comment: Two different models with same properties and different validation attributes.

Comment: @Hp_issei  ok thanks bro

Comment: Ok.welcome.Now can do it that way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use IsValidField method to only check the Years field, as follows:

```
if (ModelState.IsValidField("Years"))
{
//do something...
}
```

if you need to validate more fields just use and operator, as follows:

```
if (ModelState.IsValidField("Years") && ModelState.IsValidField("Remark"))
{
//do something...
}
```

to validate list of properties and ignore others you can do something like this in your Action method:

```
        List<string> validationProperties = new List<string> { "Years"};
        bool isValid = true;
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (validationProperties .Contains(propertyInfo.Name))
                isValid = ModelState.IsValidField(propertyInfo.Name) && isValid;

        }
        if (isValid)
        {
            // do stuff here
        }
```